# Oracle: What is a transaction?

Tags: oracle, transactions

I'm new to Oracle so I'm still learning the basics. Can someone explain to me what a transaction is? When I look it up it always seems to contain an update statement but is this a necessary feature? How is it declared? How is it any different to anonymous block?

Any help in explaining this would be much appreciated!

Comment: a transaction is something you can commit or rollback :-)

Comment: OK thanks! How do you declare it? When I type START TRANSACTION NAME = 'Add_Program' at the top of my anonymous block I get the following error: Unable to open file: "TRANSACTION.sql"

Comment: This might help you.http://www.way2tutorial.com/plsql/plsql_transaction.php

Answer (score 3):

A transaction is a logical unit of work that contains one or more SQL statements. A transaction is an atomic unit. The effects of all the SQL statements in a transaction can be either all committed (applied to the database) or all rolled back (undone from the database).

A transaction begins with the first executable SQL statement. A transaction ends when it is committed or rolled back, either explicitly with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement or implicitly when a DDL statement is issued.

Comment: How do you declare it? When I type START TRANSACTION NAME = 'Add Program' at the top of my anonymous block I get the following error: Unable to open file: "TRANSACTION.sql"

Comment: You don't have to - you just do work. When you're done, you COMMIT. There's your transaction.

Beware DDL - performing a CREATE/ALTER/DROP/TRUNCATE will give you an implicit COMMIT.

If you want to declare a transaction and create save points, you can do this, consult the DOCS - here's your linky https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1118